# Why do we create a send definition in Marketing Cloud Transactional Email and then send it in second step

Tags: marketing-cloud, transaction

Why do we create a send definition in Marketing Cloud Transactional Email?
In the steps of creating Transactional Email using Marketing Cloud API, it is given that

- first, create the Transactional Email.
- then send the email to one or more Recipients.

When we create send definition we set it up to subscriptions list and then when we send the email it is to one or more subscribers based on the contact key.

Is it possible to create a send definition and send it in one step?

Then what is the purpose of the subscription list we created when creating the send definition?